# When and Why should I care about different Container Runtimes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, linux-containers, rkt, containerd

I am trying to understand when someone should really care about the different containerRuntimes available like `docker`, `containerd`, `rkt`. I know there will be different reasons like security concerns, performace etc. Can anyone elaborate all the concerns in detail.
Also with and without considering orchestrating of containers in mind with k8.

Comment: It will be great if there is one table of difference in all container runtimes. comparing among the metrics like security, relibility, performace etc.

Comment: [This blog series](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/container-runtimes-part-1-introduction-container-r) goes into the differences a bit, explains a little more why some people might want to use not-Docker.